# Equality involving binomial coefficient in a integral

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, binomial-coefficients

Considering the integral I do not visualize and understand why:
$$F= \int \rho(\theta_1)d\theta_1 \dots\rho(\theta_n)d\theta_n \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j \ln(1+e^{-(\theta_i+\theta_j)})\stackrel{?}{=} - \binom{n}{2} \iint d\theta_1 d\theta_2 \rho(\theta_1)\rho(\theta_2) \ln(1+e^{-(\theta_1+\theta_2)}) $$

Comment: Imagine $\rho$ is a probability density function. Then what the LHS and RHS correspond to in probabilistic terms?

Comment: I' m sorry could you be more explicit pls, I'm stuck